# Issue regarding switching into other pages using nodejs

Tags: html, node.js

I have an issue with switching to other pages in node js.Here is my code below

```
//here are my global variables
const express = require('express');
var app = require("express")(); 
var bodyParser = require("body-parser"); 
const port = 3000;
var http=require('http');
var url=require('url');

//code
var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    var pathname=url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    switch(pathname){
        case '/whatYouGot':
            res.sendFile('whatYouGot.html');
        break;
        case '/#contact':
            res.sendFile('index.html');
        break;
        case '/#about' :
            res.sendFile('index.html');
        break;
        default:
            res.end('default');
        break;
    }

})
app.listen(port, () => console.log("example app listening on port %s",port));
```

I am not able to switch pages as I am getting an error like
Cannot GET /index.html
here is my url:
http://localhost:3000/index.html#contact
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since your route is only `/#contact` your url should be `http://localhost:3000/#contact`. I would advise not to use `/#contact` but, instead, `/contact` as `#` is used to handle id anchors in the frontend.